# The element next to element that have inside some specific element

Tags: css, css-selectors, ckeditor, textarea

In CSS, can I apply a style to some element next to element, that have inside some specific element.

Example:

```
<div class="container">
   <p>bla bla bla some text</p>
   <p>bla bla bla some text</p>
   <p>bla bla bla some text</p>

   <p> <img src="url-of-image.jpg" alt="something"/> </p>
   <p>this is the text that i want to apply some style, example: bold, red color</p>

   <p>bla bla bla some text</p>
   <p>bla bla bla some text</p>
   <p>bla bla bla some text</p>

   <p> <img src="url-of-image.jpg" alt="something"/> </p>
   <p>this is the text that i want to apply some style, example: bold, red color</p>

   <p>bla bla bla some text</p>
   <p>bla bla bla some text</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, I want to apply the style to the next `p`, just after some `p` that have inside an `img`.

All content inside `.container` is from database (MySQL) and is stored via POST from a `textarea` with CKEditor pluggin. This pluggin puts all `p`, the image is inserted with the same pluggin. So, users can't put a class, they just type text, insert images (not always), and when this happens (text + img), the next `p` will be the image footer, with some style. This is why I need to do it in this way.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: No, not with CSS only

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, pure CSS does not (yet) allow you to do this. You cannot select an element's parent, neither can you check if an element contains another element (`:has` in JQuery).

This will change with [Selector Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational), but support is still very limited.

Comment: Well, tanks for the info, i'll try this with javascript.